# Alexa REST Service

Tags: node.js, promise, alexa-skills-kit

I've been working on this all day, tried every solution between AMZ Forums and GIT Issues. Here is where I'm at.

My intent. It shouldn't matter, but this is an intent in a state other than the "initial" state.:

```
    'GetMondoPick':function(){
      const ref = this;
      FindMondoBottle(result =>{
        console.log("RESULT IS: "+result);
        ref.emit(":ask","Do i need to shoot myself?")
      });
    },
```

I have tried, this as well:

```
    'GetMondoPick':function(){
      FindMondoBottle(result =>{
        console.log("RESULT IS: "+result);
        this.emit(":ask","Do i need to shoot myself?")
      });
    },
```

I call the following:

```
    function FindMondoBottle(cb){
      var apiOptions = {
        host: API_ENDPOINT,
        path: API_PATH+"/products/club-items",
        method: 'GET',
        json: true
      }

      var apiRequest = http.request(apiOptions, (mondo) =>{
        console.log("Got the request atleast")
        var data = "";
        mondo.setEncoding('utf8');
        mondo.on('data', chunk => {
          data += chunk
        });
        mondo.on('end',()=>{
          console.log("Got to End")
          cb(data)
        })
      })
      apiRequest.end();
    }
```

this.emit is just not firing, at all. If it is, it's out of scope and something isn't connecting along. I have tried request-promise. I've tried fat arrow. I've tried setting a reference (As above). I've tried calling Alexa directly. I can not, for the life of me, get the scoping right on this.

What am I missing here?

Outputting the "this" object keys, i see this:
        on,emit,emitWithState,handler,i18n,locale,t,event,attributes,context,callback,name,isOverridden,response

So, it is, in fact, there to call. Also, emitWithState works just fine.

Comment: Does the request return data? Looking at the docs, `http.request` [doesn't](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) take `json` as an option

Comment: Did you try passing 'this' to 'FindMondoBottle'  instead of a callback handler and then using it in mondo.on() instead of calling callback.